# Sorting TableView column in qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I need to sort my column number 1 in TableView. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969261/how-to-sort-qml-tableview-in-qtquick-2) but I get some errors and I'm not really sure why it doesnt work.

In my TableView model qml file I have this:

```
TableView
{
    ...
    onSortIndicatorColumnChanged: model.sort(1, sortIndicatorOrder)
...
```

and in cpp file:

```
    Q_INVOKABLE virtual void sort(int column, Qt::SortOrder order=Qt::AscendingOrder)
    {
        proxyModel=new QSortFilterProxyModel;
        qDebug("Sorting by column %d", column);
        proxyModel->sort(column, order);
    }
```

Comment: you cannot call 'QSortFilterProxyModel::sort',  because it is not static, )))  there is an example here https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/widgets/itemviews/basicsortfiltermodel?h=5.13

Comment: @VahagnAvagyan thank you for your answer, I updated my question. It doesnt show any errors now but it also doesnt work.

Comment: have you set to your proxy model your abstract model? I guess you can see the debug output? Can you?

Comment: @Mikhail I cant